# Ember radio button never be cleared after exiting the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js

I have a handlebar with 5 radio buttons:

```
<ui>
            <li> <label>
            {{view Ember.RadioButton  id="option1" name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="isSelected" value=1}}
            <b>{{i18n 'kwoption1'}}</b>
        </label></li>
       <li> <label>
            {{view Ember.RadioButton id="option2" name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="controllerisSelected" value=2 valueBinding="radio1"}}
            <b>{{i18n 'kwoption2'}}</b>
        </label></li>
            <li> <label>
            {{view Ember.RadioButton id="option3" name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="isSelected" value=3}}
            <b>{{i18n 'kwoption3'}}</b>
        </label></li>
        <li> <label>
            {{view Ember.RadioButton id="option4" name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="isSelected" value=4}}
            <b>{{i18n 'kwoption4'}}</b>
        </label></li>
        <li> <label>
            {{view Ember.RadioButton id="option5" name="selectionTest" selectionBinding="isSelected" value=5}}
            <b>{{i18n 'kwoption5'}}</b>
        </label></li>
        </ui>
```

When I click on the <kbd>submit</kbd> button, it clears all radio buttons, but after exiting the screen and trying to access it again, I am getting the old selected value.

How can I clear the cache on this handlebar?

Comment: The submit does not clear anything automatically, the question is what action the submit triggers and what the function `isSelected` returns. Is there a selection when you enter the view without having it sent before?

Comment: the submit has the below code :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue by adding init function to the  Ember.RadioButton  by setting the selection value to "" as below:

```
Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName : "input",
    type : "radio",
    attributeBindings : [ "name", "type", "value", "checked:checked:" ],
    click : function() {
        cValue=(this.set("selection", this.$().val()).value).toString();
        this.set("selection", this.$().val());
    },
    init: function() {
        cValue=null;
        this.set("selection", "");
    },
    checked : function() {
        return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");  
    }.property()
});
```

Thanks all for your corporation

Answer (score 0):

In your submit action, call a method that clears all selections after the values are no longer needed, but before transitioning route.

Comment: Sorry I am new to ember ,Can you please help me  how to do that